# Drawing Nested Ovals and Enumerating them

Tags: java, swing, drawing, awt, java-2d

Trying to write some kind of Gui and need to draw nested 4096 ovals and want to enumerate them (from 1 to 4096). However, couldn't figure out how drawOval method works (more specifically, have little problem about finding math formula for this, and using coordinate parameters in the method)

Here is what I did so far:
This code draws 1 circle and tried to decrease parameters but didn't work out. Could you explain how to use draw method's parameters properly and how to make a formula for this?

Secondly, I want to give each oval a number, how to do that?

```
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D obj = (Graphics2D)g;
        obj.setRenderingHint(
                RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        obj.setColor(Color.black);
        obj.drawOval(0,0, getWidth()+1, getHeight()+1);

    }

    private static void make() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new deneme2());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            make();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: I suspect this is similar to something like **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125847/circles-in-circles-fading-out-creating-a-target/16126039#16126039)**

Comment: thx for the answer, could you give some tips for adding numbers to each circle?

Comment: What do you mean "adding numbers"?  Do you want to render text on them, like a dart board?

Comment: yeah, for each circle.

Comment: @nihirus, then add a drawstring(...) statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in additional to the example provide [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125847/circles-in-circles-fading-out-creating-a-target/16126039#16126039) which shows how to draw multiple consecutive circles and demonstrates how one might render to text to them...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Circles {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Circles();
    }

    public Circles() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
            int padding = fm.getHeight() + 4;
            int width = getWidth() - 1 - padding;
            int height = getHeight() - 1 - padding;

            int radius = Math.min(width, height);
            int x = (padding + (width - radius)) / 2;
            int y = (padding + (height - radius)) / 2;
            g2d.drawOval(x, y, radius, radius);

            String text = "This is a test";

            int centerX = (padding + radius) / 2;
            int centerY = (padding + radius) / 2;

            x = (centerX - (fm.stringWidth(text)) / 2);
            y = centerY - (radius / 2);
            g2d.drawString(text, x, y);

            x = centerX - (radius / 2);
            g2d.drawString(text, x, centerY);

            x = (centerX - (fm.stringWidth(text)) / 2);
            y = centerY + (radius / 2);
            g2d.drawString(text, x, y);

            x = (centerX - (fm.stringWidth(text)) / 2);
            y = centerY - (radius / 2);
            g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(90), getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
            g2d.drawString(text, x, y);

            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }       
}
```

I also suggest you farmiluarise yourself with [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)

Comment: thanks for codes. I am learning java swing for 2 days and will improve myself. 

one last question, dont want you to write a code, just need a tip. I want to fill the gaps between two ellipses with yellow color. Color tone should be intense at the beginning of the each gap then slowly be lighter. That process should be repeatet for each gap between ellipses seperately.(Color tone will be between 0-255, so for each gap it will start from 0 to 255 until reaching the end of the gap) Is there a method to do this or do I have to define a method for this job?

Comment: I think you want to take a look at [RadialGradientPaint](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/RadialGradientPaint.html)